# Passing Array to a function and Adding it through Recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

What em trying to do is pass the array to a function which will add all the array elements and return the output. Please help me. i dont know what i am doing wrong in this :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 5

int arraySum(int *dArr,int lim);

int main()
{
    int array[MAX] = {9,7,4,2,10};
    printf("%d", arraySum(array, MAX));
    return 0;
}
int arraySum(int *dArr,int lim)
{
    int Ans;
    if(lim>0)
    Ans = dArr[lim] + arraySum(*dArr, lim--);
    return Ans;
}
```

Comment: `dArr` is a pointer to an integer. Dereferencing it gives you an integer. Anyway, for practical purposes, use `std::accumulate`.

Comment: C and C++ are not interchangeable technologies.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use recursion for this, in real-world applications.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You're accessing `array[MAX]`, which is undefined behaviour.
2. Your function returns the uninitialized `Ans` when `lim` is zero.
3. The first argument to `arraySum` in the recursive call is wrong.
4. The use of `lim--` is wrong.

Since this looks like homework, I'll let you figure out how to fix these problems. If this *isn't* homework, you might want to consider whether recursion is the right tool for the job.

Comment: i did set '--lim' and the value to lim to be passed to 4. (removed array[MAX]) initialized global value of Ans = 0; dont get ur 3rd point

Comment: @user1804407: Think about the *types* of the arguments to `arraySum()`.

Comment: okay so i am passing just arraySum(dArr, lim--). still i am getting an error saying operation on lim undefined

Answer (score 1):

You run into undefined behavior on `dArr[lim]`, because `lim` is `5` and the array has elements `0...4`.

You also get undefined behavior when `lim==0`, because you return an un-initialized `Ans`. When you declare it, initialize it to `dArr[0]`.

After you fix this, you'll want to pass `dArr` itself further in the recursion, as `dArr` only returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `MAX` to `4` and change the `if(lim>0)` condition as  `if(lim>=0)`

This will make your recursion to add as `dArr[4]+dArr[3]+dArr[2]+dArr[1]+dArr[0]` i.e. all 5 elements of the array.

EDIT: Corrected program:

```
   int main()
   {
     int array[MAX] = {9,7,4,2,10};
     printf("%d", arraySum(array, MAX-1));
     return 0;
   }

    int Ans = 0;
    int arraySum(int *dArr,int lim)
    {
       if(lim>=0){
          Ans = dArr[lim] + arraySum(dArr, lim-1);
        }
       return Ans;
    }
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
 
int arraySum(int *dArr,int lim);
 
int main()
{
    int array[5] = {9,7,4,2,10};
    printf("%d", arraySum(array, 4));
    return 0;
}
int Ans=0;
int arraySum(int *dArr,int lim)
{
    printf("l%d ", lim);
    if(lim>0)
    Ans = dArr[lim] + arraySum(*dArr, --lim);
    return Ans;
}
NO i still have a problem

Comment: @user1804407: `if (lim >= 0)` and not `if (lim > 0)`. Also `dArr[lim] + arraySum(*dArr, --lim);` should be `dArr[lim] + arraySum(dArr, --lim);`

Comment: @user1804407: If you are using `--lim` in place of `lim--` then start the index at `5` not `4`. Otherwise it ignore your `dArr[4]` and starts from `dArr[3]`. Remove `*` from `arraySum(*dArr, --lim);`.

Comment: okay so i am passing just arraySum(dArr, lim--). still i am getting an error saying operation on lim undefined. everything is as u said

Answer (score 0):

Remember that computers treat **0** as the first number, so your array will number from element[0] to element[4]. your code starts from five and counts down to one, which means elements[5] in this case will return garbage, because the index does not exist. pass Lim - 1 into the function or manually changed the value in your function.

```
ArraySum(Array, MAX - 1);
```

OR

```
ArraySum(//....)
{
lim--;
//code here....
}
```

EDIT: you also need to initialize ans to some value, so if an array of zero elements is passed the function wont return an uninitialized variable.

Comment: I think it is OK to not initialize the value of Ans because the value is assigned to Ans and not summed up

Answer (score 0):

```
int arraySum(int *dArr,int lim)
{
    int Ans;
    if(lim>=0) // note the change here
    Ans = dArr[lim] + arraySum(dArr, --lim); // note the --lim change here
    return Ans;
}
```

1. You should invoke this with lim as 4 and not 5. Because the array has 5 integers starting from index 0 to index 4. 5th index is out of bounds.
2. --lim instead of lim-- because lim-- is post decrement. That means the value is first passed and then decremented. Hence everytime your arraySum function gets the value as 4 instead of 3, 2, 1 and 0 (as per your expectation). --lim is pre-decrement.